Escaping double quotes in an INSERT statement for SQL Server
Using Python 3 and the re module, how can I escape double quotes in an INSERT statement for SQL Server?
I've tried a bunch of different ways but SQL Server always throws an error with the formatting.
Here is an example:
INSERT INTO [events] VALUES ('<span style=\"font-size:14px;\"><span style=\"font-family:\'Times New Roman\', Times, serif;\">

My most recent try was this:
escaped_statement = re.sub(r'\"', r'\"\"', escaped_statement)

But that returns this:
<span style='\"\"font-size:14px;


The double quotes isn't the problem it's the single quotes, and if you parametrised that isn't a problem either. Classic XY Problem.

Why would you try to escape quotes by adding more quotes? Also, using style directly in a tag is not optimal. Why aren't you using a class?

Does this answer your question? How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?

Because T-SQL uses 2 of the character to escape, @OysterShucker . SELECT '''' would return '.

@ThomA But they don't have 2 of the character "", they have this \"\".

If you're escaping strings from outside world, you have already lost the game, read about sql injection. Use parameters when doing sql, and it should be all OK

Your example should be like this: INSERT INTO [events] VALUES ('<span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:''Times New Roman'', Times, serif;">') 
Why do you need to escape double quotes, it doesn't matter in SQL, any content inside single quotes 'string' consider string literal. and if you want to escape a single quotes you can simpy use double single quotes '' instead of single single quote '.
